# How to make this type of graph in Android?

Tags: java, android, graph

I've been looking into some graphing libraries but have only found ones for bar graphs, pie charts, scatter plots, and other things that are not what I'm looking for... How do I make a graph with directed lines of different thicknesses between labels, indicating the strength of the connection between the two? (Also, what is this called, more specifically than "graph"?)

Here's a sketch:
[image: graph]

Comment: Seems a little focused. Maybe roll your own. Shouldn't be too complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following for the circle

```
canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);
```

for the lines you can try using the

```
canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, paint);
```

with different paint objects.

You can also have a look at the android.graphics.Path class.

Thanks!